# Where does Transmit 4 store temporary downloaded files?

Tags: macos, file-transfer, ftp

If you have two remote locations in Transmit 4, say an S3 and an FTP location, and you move a file between these two locations, Transmit will automatically download that file, and then upload it.

Where does Transmit 4 store these temporary files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this out by yourself:

1. Start Transmit
2. Execute `sudo opensnoop -n Transmit` in Terminal
3. Initiate transfer from S3 to FTP

This will list all created/opened files, it shouldn't be difficult to identify the temporary files.

Comment: dude, you're a genius. I didn't know about this snoop app. Will research it, just used it, perfect. thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The opensnoop program is remarkably useful, but to answer the actual question in case somebody is in a quick bind, for Transmit 4 the location of the temporary files is:

```
/Volumes/<Macintosh HD>/Users/<current user>/Library/Caches/Cleanup At Startup/Transmit/server-to-server-B18AC7A9-81C6-4AAD-8F2C-6CD70E65D7FD/data-file-being-transferred
```

Transmit appears to clean up after itself within a second or two of the upload completing. The name and path of the folder implies to me that the system might clean it up if Transmit doesn't get the chance.

Update 26th July 2018:
Latest version (5.1.5) appears to store a file at a time in:

```
/Volumes/<Macintosh HD>/Users/<current user>/Library/Caches/Transmit/[UUID]/<host server>/path/to/file
```

The files are cleaned up more or less immediately after uploading to the destination server (afaict) but the subdirectories seem to stick around for some period of time (such that I now have ~600 files in the Caches/Transmit directory. Perhaps this is used for some logging or history, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In my case it seems files peeked on with Transmit Quick Look are not removed. I noticed files in there that I quick looked at weeks ago, just recovered about 10 GB worth of disk space right now!

Comment: Thanks for the July 2018 update Owen. My Transmit 5.10.4 cache is over 5GB from 2022. I use BBEdit as an external editor and every file I edit is saved and never purged / cleared do you have a solution for this? (I am not using Quick Look). I send this question to Panic support but did not hear back.